# Expressing a function as a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hi so I know how to express a vector as a linear combination of another vector but now I've been given a function and it's thrown me a bit, just wondering if anyone can assist. The question is:

In the vector space $\  V = {f : R → R},$ express

$\ 3x^2 + 5x − 5 $

as a linear combination of

$\ x^2 + 2x + 1, 2x^2 + 5x + 4, x^2 + 3x + 6.
 $

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Check out this video, which explains how polynomials are treated as vectors in Linear Algebra. https://www.lem.ma/h In later lessons, many problems like the one you described here are considered.

Answer (score 3):

It exactly the same idea as in the case of "geometric" vectors.  You just want to find numbers $c_1,c_2,c_3$ so that $$3x^2+5x-5=c_1(x^2+2x+1)+c_2(2x^2+5x+4)+c_3(x^2+3x+6)$$  If you are stuck, try expanding the right side and grouping the terms by powers of $x$, then set these coefficients equal to the corresponding coefficients on the left side.

Comment: ... and solve a linear system with 3 equations in the 3 unknowns $c_1,c_2,c_3$.

Comment: @user75296 Thanks for your reply! so I end up with $$\ c_1x^2+c_22x^2+c_3x^2 = 3x^2 $$ etc How to I continue on though?

Answer (score 0):

From $$3x^2+5x-5=c_1(x^2+2x+1)+c_2(2x^2+5x+4)+c_3(x^2+3x+6)$$ we have (by matching coefficients of corresponding powers): $$\begin{align}c_1+2c_2+c_3&=3\\2c_1+5c_2+3c_3&=5\\c_1+4c+6c_3&=-5\end{align}$$ Sovling this system of equations, we find $$\begin{align}c_1&=3\\c_2&=1\\c_3&=-2\end{align}$$